# SASS Nesting not working as expected

Tags: css, sass

I am setting up a new Angular (version4.1.1) project.
The project builds fine, test are executed and passing.

I do however have a problem with using SASS in this project:

I do not seem to be able to nest any rules. This snippet of SASS does not have any impact on my site at all.

```
ul#sinup_progress {
    li.signup_progress_state {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 20px;
        a {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border: 1px dotted #ff0000;
        }
    }
}
```

Changing it to a non nested version like this:

```
ul#sinup_progress {


}
li.signup_progress_state {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;

}
a {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px dotted #ff0000;
}
```

Then it works absolutely fine - obviously this hardly worth to be called SASS anymore. Does anyone have an idea what could be going on?

Comment: Doesn't SASS not use "Curly Brackets" and "Semi-Colons" - You would nest each element under its parent to style

Comment: @MikeDiglio It most certainly does use them.

Comment: @J.Titus isn't that SCSS and not SASS?

Comment: Looks like it works to me: https://jsfiddle.net/zsw8cyry/ - Are you processing the SASS before using it on the site?

Comment: @MikeDiglio Same thing, buddy. `.scss` is the file extension for SASS.

Comment: @J.Titus rofl - so I just read like 20 posts about SCSS and SASS and didn't realized what it had evolved into. I have been using them as different filetypes (like sass was used years ago) rather than adopting this new scss style. Well, thank you for the insight :)

Comment: I can simplify the SASS to just nested tags without any classes and it still behaves the same way. If the SASS would not be processed at all then the 'non nested' version would not work either.

Comment: I took the nested SASS to here and it compiles fine https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: I guess it must be something evironmentally